# Check if the string abbreviation and copy the full string. (Vba)

Tags: arrays, string, vba, excel

I am working on building data historical exclusions of corporate debt issues in the primary market.

I need macro

1. Read each cell and check if it contains an abbreviation of many
   options and, according to the abbreviation, copy the full value in
   the next empty cell of the same row.
2. Copy Previous string value to "P" for the corresponding
   abbreviation found in bullet 1, in the next empy cell of the same row.
3. Copy all Previous string value to "E" for the corresponding "P" found in 
   bullet 2 and abbreviation found in bullet 1, in the next empy cell of the 
   same row.

After this repeat for all the abbreviations found in the cell.

```
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              what I have                               | 
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   |                                 A                                  |
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | B.Corp. - 2P. 5E,6E y 9E                                           |
| 2 | B.Corp - 2P, 2E y 5E - C.D.N. 2P 4E                                |
| 3 | B.Corp. 1P 6E,7E,9E,10E,11E,12E,13E,14E,15E,17E,19E,20E,21E,22E,23E|
| 4 | I.C.P. 2P 5E 6E y 7E -  B.Corp. 3P 2E y 3E                         |
| 5 | I.C.P.  4P 1E- I.C.P 3P 3E- B.Corp. 1P 1E 3E 4E y 6E               |
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For the case of row number 5

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                            what I need                                                                        |
+---+--------------------------+---+---+--------------------------+---+---+-----------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |             B            | C | D |            E             | F | G |H                | I | J | K | L | M |
+---+--------------------------+---+---+--------------------------+---+---+-----------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| 5 |Instrumento de Corto Plazo| 4 | 1 |Instrumento de Corto Plazo| 3 | 3 |Bono Corporativo | 1 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 6 |
+---+--------------------------+---+---+--------------------------+---+---+-----------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I have dealt with the following codes, but they do not work at all:

```
Sub abv_to_full()

If InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "Corp", 1) Or InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "BC", 1) Then
Cells(a, 5).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Bonos Corporativos" 'English: corporate bonds

ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "C.D.N.", 1) Or InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "CDN", 1) Then
Cells(a, 5).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Certificados de Depositos" 'English: certificates of deposits / term deposits

ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "I.C.P", 1) Or InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "ICP", 1) Then
Cells(a, 5).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Instrumentos de Corto Plazo" 'English: short term instruments

ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "BS", 1) Or InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "Subo", 1) Then
Cells(a, 5).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Bonos Subordinados" 'English: Subordinated Bonds

ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "BAF", 1) Or InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "B.A.F.", 1) Then
Cells(a, 5).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Bonos de Arrendamiento Financiero" 'English: financial lease bonds

ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "BH", 1) Or InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "BHIP", 1) Then
Cells(a, 5).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Bonos Hipotecarios" 'English: mortgage securities

ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(a, 5), "IRD", 1) Then
Cells(a, 5).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Instrumentos Representativos de Deuda" 'English: instruments representing debt

End If

End Sub
```

```
Sub second_try()
Dim start_, startp_ As Integer
Dim ant_tipo, nvo_tipo

ant_tipo = Array("Corp", "BC", "C.D.N.", "CDN", "I.C.P.", "ICP", "BS", "Subo", "BAF", "B.A.F.", "IRD", "BHIP", "BH")
nvo_tipo = Array("Bonos Corporativos", "Bonos Corporativos", "Certificados de Deposito", "Certificados de Deposito", "Instrumentos de Corto Plazo", "Instrumentos de Corto Plazo", "Bonos Subordinados", "Bonos Subordinados", "Bonos de Arrendamiento Financiero", "Bonos de Arrendamiento Financiero", "Instrumentos Representativos de Deuda", "Bonos Hipotecarios", "Bonos Hipotecarios")

cont = 0
Start = 1
Do
pos = InStr(Start, Cells(a, 5), ant_tipo(i), 0)
    If pos > 0 Then
      Start = pos + 1  'alternatively: start = pos + Len(srch)
      Cells(a, 5).Offset(0, 2 + cont).Value = nvo_tipo(i)
      cont = cont + 1
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
Loop While pos > 0
End sub
```

Comment: Is it really the case that the separators in the original data can vary, the way you show it?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it is data that has been registered manually for years by different people.

Comment: The first thing is that the Cell addressing is the wrong way round, for row 5 column 1 it should be Cells (5,1)

Answer (score 2):

Tray this code. (Comments inside)

```
   Sub Break_String()
        Dim sarray() As String
        Dim stemp As String
        Dim ant_tipo, nvo_tipo
        Dim rcell As Range
        Dim icounter As Integer
        'yuo must add also value for "I.C.P"
        ant_tipo = Array("Corp", "BC", "C.D.N.", "CDN", "I.C.P", "I.C.P.", "ICP", "BS", "Subo", "BAF", "B.A.F.", "IRD", "BHIP", "BH")
        nvo_tipo = Array("Bonos Corporativos", "Bonos Corporativos", "Certificados de Deposito", "Certificados de Deposito", "Instrumentos de Corto Plazo", "Instrumentos de Corto Plazo", "Instrumentos de Corto Plazo", "Bonos Subordinados", "Bonos Subordinados", "Bonos de Arrendamiento Financiero", "Bonos de Arrendamiento Financiero", "Instrumentos Representativos de Deuda", "Bonos Hipotecarios", "Bonos Hipotecarios")

        'loop for all data cells
        For c = 1 To Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

            Set rcell = Cells(c, 1)
            stemp = rcell.Value

            'replace , and - and y on space
            'prevents any missing spaces between data
            stemp = Replace(stemp, ",", " ")
            stemp = Replace(stemp, "-", " ")
            stemp = Replace(stemp, "y", " ")
            icounter = 1 'used for select first empty cell in a row
            'split using space
            sarray() = Split(stemp)

            For i = LBound(sarray) To UBound(sarray)
            'Delete spaces
                stemp = Trim(sarray(i))
            'check if name
                For j = LBound(ant_tipo) To UBound(ant_tipo)
                    If InStr(stemp, ant_tipo(j)) Then
                        rcell.Offset(0, icounter).Value = nvo_tipo(j)
                        icounter = icounter + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
            'assign values for P and E
            'check if the fisrt sign is a number to eliminate company names
            If InStr("123456789", Left(stemp, 1)) Then
                If Right(stemp, 1) = "P" Or Right(stemp, 1) = "E" Then
                    rcell.Offset(0, icounter).Value = Mid(stemp, 1, Len(stemp) - 1)
                    icounter = icounter + 1
                End If
             End If
            Next i
        Next c
    End Sub
```

Comment: Nice - I guess would need modifying slightly to deal with 2-digit numbers but it already answers OP's question.

Comment: @Tom Sharpe, of course you're right, I just modified the code by including two-digit numbers .

Comment: Thank you very much adarti, Tom and everyone who participated rating my question. Your answer has helped me to understand how to refer to all the elements inside one array and to know a little better about the handling of string and numerical values within a same cell.

Comment: I already did, but I have less than 15 reputation at the moment. - @adarti